# get JSON fields without loop

Tags: ruby, json

Is there any way to store each of the `openAsk` values in an array below without looping through every one?

```
require 'httparty'
response =HTTParty.get("https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v1/candles?instrument=EUR_USD&count=500&candleFormat=bidask&granularity=H1&dailyAlignment=0&alignmentTimezone=America%2FNew_York")

puts response['candles'][0]['openAsk']
puts response['candles'][1]['openAsk']
.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get the "not looping requirement". Do you mean "not manually going through each one"?

Anyway, if you're interested in digging out the values, you could do it like this:

```rb
open_ask_prices = response["candles"].map { |pricing| pricing["openAsk"] }
```

See more here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map